# Adding themes in android doesnt work

Tags: android, themes

I created a theme and placed it the values category:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
          <style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
                <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
            </style>
        </resources>
```

// my Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.DmitriMakovetskiy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="4.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 


 **android:theme="@style/GreenText"**
        >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".LayoutsActivity" 

            >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


The application cant launch.. what am I doing wrong!?!?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make theme you have to create following files.

1. themes.xml in values folder
2. styles.xml in values folder
3. Apply theme in AndroidManifest.xml

**themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTheme.TextView</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
          <style name="MyTheme.Textview" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
                <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
            </style>
        </resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it was a typo but you are not actually writing the ** right?

```
**android:theme="@style/GreenText"**
```

Also, I am not sure you can make TextAppereance parent. Try without that.

Another thing, was your application working before that? because you are using a relative name for the activity (".LayoutsActivity") and you should use the complete package name.

Are your XMLs compiling? Hard to debug without the error.